# Create dynamic conditions list of ranges for numpy.select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm relatively new to Python and hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

For context, I want create a new column in a Pandas dataframe that assigns a score of linear integer values to a new column based on values in an existing column being within certain ranges.

There is a lower and upper bound, say 0 and 0.75. Being below or above those respectively will yield the lowest / highest value.

Written manually with relatively few conditions it looks like this using np.select():

```
d = {'col1': [-1, 0, .1, .6, .8],'col2': [-4,-0.02, 0.07, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

conditions = [
    (df['col1'] < 0),
    (df['col1'] >= 0) & (df['col1'] <= .25),
    (df['col1'] >= .25) & (df['col1'] <= .5),
    (df['col1'] >= .5) & (df['col1'] <= .75),
    (df['col1'] >= .75)
]

values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

df['col3'] = np.select(conditions,values,default=None)
```

I would like to be able to dynamically divide the mid-range between bounds into many more conditions, which is easy enough using np.linspace.

Where I'm having trouble is in assigning the values. I have tried to do this using pd.cut and operating on a list to feed into np.select. This is the closest I have come with these:

```
d = {'col1': [-1, 0, .1, .6, .8],'col2': [-4,-0.02, 0.07, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

conditions_no = 9 # Choose number of conditions to divide the mid-range
choices = [n for n in range(1, conditions_no + 2)] # Assign values to apply starting from 1

mid_range = np.linspace(0,.75,conditions_no) # Divide mid-range by number of conditions
mid_range = np.append(mid_range[0],mid_range) # Repeat lower bound at start for < condition

cols = ['df["col1"]' for c in range(0, conditions + 1)] # Generate list of column references

conditions = list(zip(cols,mid_range)) # List with range as values, df as key

conditions = [f'{k} >= {v}' for k, v in conditions] # Combine column references and 

conditions[0] = conditions[0].replace('>=','<') # Change first condition to less than lower bound

conditions = conditions[::-1] # Reverse values and assigned choices to check > highest value first
choices = choices[::-1]
```

Here the conditions are a list of strings rather than code:

```
['df["col1"] >= 0.75',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.65625',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.5625',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.46875',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.375',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.28125',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.1875',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.09375',
 'df["col1"] >= 0.0',
 'df["col1"] < 0.0']
```

So they understandably throw an error:

```
df['col3'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=None) 
# TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray
```

I understand that eval() might be able to help here, but haven't been able to find a way to get that to run with np.select. I've also read that it's best to try and avoid using eval().

This is the effort so far using pd.cut:

```
conditions = 9
choices = [n for n in range(1, conditions + 2)]

mid_range = np.linspace(0,.75,conditions)
mid_range = np.append(-float("inf"),mid_range)
mid_range = np.append(mid_range,float("inf"))

df['col3'] = pd.cut(df['col1'], mid_range, labels=choices)
df['col4'] = pd.cut(df['col2'], mid_range, labels=choices)
```

This works, but assigns a categorical that I then can't operate on as needed:

```
df['col3'] + df['col4'] 
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Categorical' and 'Categorical'
```

After everything I've looked up, I keep coming back to np.select as likely being the best solution here. However, I can't figure out how to dynamically create the conditions - are any of these efforts along the right lines or is there a better approach I should look at?